# Save an Excel file and export it to pdf with a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have never written VBA code, but I checked on internet for some information.

My wish is the following: I have an Excel file with 3 sheets. On one of them, I'd like to add one button which can:

1. Save the totality of my Excel file following this naming convention: `[name of a cells of a page]_AP_[date of today].xls`.
2. Save one of the sheets in a .pdf file.
3. Print 2 of the 3 sheets while adjusting the contents.

I already started something, but I'm really bad at programming:

```
Public Sub Savefile_Click() 'copie sauvegarde classeur

' save my file following a name
Dim nom As String
Dim chemin As String
Dim wSheet As Worksheet

    chemin = "C:\Users\aaa\Desktop"
    nom = [Q13].Value & "_" & Day(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Year(Date) _
          & ".xlsm"
   With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs Filename:=chemin & nom
    .Close
    rep = MsgBox("Fichier excell sauvegardé")
    End With

' ... and print my active sheet (where the button will stay)
For Each wSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If wSheet.Visible Then wSheet.PrintOut
Next

'Save my page 'offre' in pdf on my desktop and print it
   Worksheets("OFFRE A ENVOYER").Range("A1:i47").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=[Q13].Value & "_Offre de prix", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

After that there will be another option and details, but this is really the base.

Answer (score 1):

1) Save as Excel

```
Dim nom As String

nom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Q13").Value & "AP" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xls"
thisworkbook.saveas sPath & nom 'Define path first, don't forget the \ at the end.
```

Even better would be to create a named range from range "Q13" and use:

```
nom = thisworkbook.names("Something").referstorange.value
```

To make the link dynamic in case you insert a column or row which shifts all your ranges.

2) Save workbook as PDF

```
    ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, sPath & sFile 'Define here .pdf
```

3) 
"print 2 of the 3sheets with adjusting the contenant of a "

I'm not sure if I get this one...

Print command is given by:

```
Set oSheet= thisworkbook.sheets(2)  

with oSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = "$A1$1:$Q$40"
    ...
```

'Any other properties: http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Excel/AllpropertiesofPageSetup.htm

```
end with
oSheet.printout
```

Which ever way you want to program this in order to retrieve the sheets that you need to print. 
You can loop through the sheets with a counter and put if statements to add conditions.

```
dim oSheet as Excel.worksheet
dim iCnt as integer    

For each oSheet in thisworkbook.sheets
    iCnt = iCnt + 1
    'Include conditions here 
    If ... then 'Whatever condition
        set oSheet = thisworkbook.sheets(iCnt)
        'Print
    end if
next oSheet
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you   ...i was searching this. this worked very well.

Option Explicit
Sub SvMe() 'Save filename as value of A1 plus the current date

```
Dim newFile As String, fName As String
 ' Don't use "/" in date, invalid syntax
fName = Range("A1").Value
newFile = fName & " " & Format$(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
 ' Change directory to suit
ChDir _
"C:\Users\user\Desktop" 'YOU MUST Change USER NAME to suit
ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:=newFile
```

End Sub

this 
1. saves my file in pdf format and 
2. does not prompt me for attending save as dialog box
3. saves file using cell value in A1 and date stamp